# How to add a menu item to RibbonMenu

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, ribbonx

I have placed a RibbonMenu in the VSTO ribbon using the designer. Then I saw that I cannot add items at design time so I am trying to add them programmatically when the ribbon is initialized.

I hav tried with this:

```
        RibbonMenu control = this.Factory.CreateRibbonMenu();
        control.Label = "Formatear";
        MnuDNI.Items.Add(control);
```

But an exception is thrown telling that the items collection cannot be modified.

How can I do it?

Comment: When and where do you run the code specified? Where does the `MnuDNI` control come from? Is it a ribbon menu?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev that code is Load method of the ribbon.

Comment: Try to go through the article I mentioned in my post if you want to use the ribbon designer or controls at runtime. Otherwise, I'd recommend switching to the ribbon XML. Note, you can export the existing UI created using the designer and continue with ribbon XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Walkthrough: Update the controls on a ribbon at run time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-updating-the-controls-on-a-ribbon-at-run-time?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) shows how to deal with ribbon controls created using a ribbon designer.

But I'd recommend using ribbon callbacks instead, so you will be aware what is going on and what controls should be displayed. In case of ribbon XML you may consider using the [dynamicMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#dynamicmenu) control which provides the `getContent` callback which allows providing an XML string that contains the contents of this dynamic menu. For example, a possible declaration of the menu could look like that:

```
<menu xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <button id="dynaButton" label="Button" 
    onAction="OnAction" imageMso="FoxPro"/>
  <toggleButton id="dynaToggleButton" label="Toggle Button" 
    onAction="OnToggleAction" image="logo.bmp"/>
  <menuSeparator id="div2"/>
  <dynamicMenu id="subMenu" label="Sub Menu" getContent="GetSubContent" />
</menu>
```

The callback signature should look in the following way:

```
C#: string GetContent(IRibbonControl control)
VBA: Sub GetContent(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef content)
C++: HRESULT GetContent([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] BSTR *pbstrContent)
Visual Basic: Function GetContent(control As IRibbonControl) As String
```

Read more about that in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Hello, thanks. That walkthrough shows what I was missing. I set `Dynamic` property to `true` and it worked. That property could be set at design time. Maybe, the behaviour is similar to `dynamicMenu` control you talked about.

Comment: If you generate the ribbon XML from your designer you can see what the Dynamic property is for.

Answer (score 0):

It is the other way around - you can add them at design time, but not at run-time. But you can make items invisible and hide/show them as needed simulating dynamically added items.

Comment: My first idea was to do this at design time, but I did not find a way. When I see RibbonMenu properties in designer, I did not find an Items property or something like that.

Comment: I [personally never liked the Ribbon designer- I prefer to maybe use its XML as a startling point, but like to hardcode or dynamically create the XML in my code at runtime.